# Boostrap tooltip triggers hover event on parent element when pointer is on it before it is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hover, tooltip

So I have this markup

```
<div class="col-md-12 hypoteka" id="hypoteka1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="clickable">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                        <img src="whaever.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 class="text-center banka">whaever.</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-3x fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center splatka" title="Splátka" data-toggle="tooltip">
                        <span class="hodnota">730</span>€ / mes.
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 fixacia text-center" title="Fixácia" data-toggle="tooltip">
                        <i class="fa fa-hourglass"></i>
                        <span class="hodnota">2</span>roky
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center urok" title="Úrok" data-toggle="tooltip">
                        <i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>
                        <span class="hodnota">1,85</span>%
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 preplatenie text-center" title="Preplatenie"
                    data-toggle="tooltip">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    <span class="hodnota">7 900</span>€
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="row">
            <p class="hodnotenie-text text-center">Hodnotenie</p></div>
            <div class="row">
                <p class="hodnotenie-cislo text-right">8/10</p></div>
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-balance-scale"></i>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this js

```
$('.clickable').hover(function (e) {
    $(this).find('.fa-chevron-right').toggleClass('fa-5x call-to-action');
});


$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    placement: 'bottom'
});
```

I captured the behavior [here](https://youtu.be/yWNXVRS77bY)

As you can see in the video, when the pointer hovers over the bootstrap tooltip before the animation finishes hiding it, it triggers the hover event on the clickable div.

I tried doing `e.preventDefault()` on hidden.bs.tooltip but does nothing. I cannot explain it. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the bootstrap tooltip is not created inside the `.clickable` container on which your `hover` action is defined.
When you mouse over the tooltip, you are moving outside the `.clickable` container, and so when you move mouse out from the tooltip, the `hover` event is fired again.

This can be seen better if you add a delay to the tooltip ([example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYaWLG) - 2 sec delay when showing/hiding tooltips). Try moving your mouse over and out of the tooltips before they disappear.

Comment: I thought of this, and I checked and it is created inside that .clickable div. And even if it went outside, it would then toggle twice, once for going outside and once for returning back.

Comment: Did you try using `event.stopPropagation()` on the tooltip to stop it from propagating the hover event up the DOM tree?